# Kill app in ios actually does not kill from OS

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I m using  Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => { Thread.CurrentThread.Abort(); });
            System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().Kill(); this in xamarin.forms to kill app in ios through dependency service.

But actually it is not killing the app when i press the home button it is still showing.

Can anyone help me out of this?

Comment: Why are you doing this?  It is not normal behavior and the iOS guideline specifically prohibit it.

Comment: @jason Thanks for quick reply,actually i m having requirement of killing the app do you have any idea ?

Comment: You need to tell whoever gave you that requirement that it violates Apple's rules and will cause the app to be rejected by the App store.

Comment: Ok thnx Jason for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible. From the Apple technical Q&A (https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1561/_index.html):

> A: There is no API provided for gracefully terminating an iOS
>   application.
>
> In iOS, the user presses the Home button to close applications. Should
>   your application have conditions in which it cannot provide its
>   intended function, the recommended approach is to display an alert for
>   the user that indicates the nature of the problem and possible actions
>   the user could take — turning on WiFi, enabling Location Services,
>   etc. Allow the user to terminate the application at their own
>   discretion.

Although the documentation is pretty old, this still stands. Even if you do find some way to implement it, it will never be allowed to the App Store.